# in_array doesn't seem to work on arrays

Tags: php

My php script:

```
$cont = array();
$slq_get_previous_country_list = "SELECT country FROM aw_countries_v2 WHERE id ='11120'";
$result_previous_country_list = mysql_query($slq_get_previous_country_list);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_previous_country_list))
{
   $cont[] = $row['country'];
}

print_r($cont);                 
$not_data = array();    
$new_contry = array("Greece",
                    "Israel",
                    "Macedonia - The Frm Yugoslav Rep Of",
                    "Malta",
                    "India");


foreach($cont as $c)
{
  if(in_array($c, $new_contry)) 
    {
        echo $c."\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $not_data[] = $c;
    }   
}

print_r($not_data);
```

`$cont` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Belgium
    [1] =>  Cyprus
    [2] =>  Czech Republic
    [3] =>  Fiji
    [4] =>  Finland
    [5] =>  Greece
    [6] =>  Iceland
    [7] =>  Ireland
    [8] =>  Israel
    [9] =>  Macedonia - The Frm Yugoslav Rep Of
    [10] =>  Malaysia
    [11] =>  Malta
    [12] =>  Monaco
    [13] =>  Poland
    [14] =>  South Africa
    [15] => Austria
)
```

`$not_data` array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] =>  Belgium
        [1] =>  Cyprus
        [2] =>  Czech Republic
        [3] =>  Fiji
        [4] =>  Finland
        [5] =>  Iceland
        [6] =>  Ireland
        [7] =>  Malaysia
        [8] =>  Monaco
        [9] =>  Poland
        [10] =>  South Africa
        [11] => Austria
    )
```

The result:

```
array(
      [0] => austria
     );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its case and space sensitive

Comment: Have u tried to debug 'c' in the else part?

Comment: can you try incrementing `$not_data` index manually at the place of using `$not_data[]=`

Comment: @sgt debug 'c' means?

Comment: Print 'c' inside else part and see what you are getting..

Comment: grrrrr!!!! it took me 4 hours!!!

Comment: By the way: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php <- the function you are looking for

Comment: What is your script actually meant to do?

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces in your strings, and the `in_array` function is space and case sensitive, so try adding this as a precursor:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_previous_country_list))
{
   $cont[] = trim($row['country']);
}
```

You may also want to try `strtolower` to compare both array's string values without case worries.

Also, it is recommended to NOT use MySQL_ but to develop up to ***MySQLi*** or even ***PDO***.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... but its already an age old post.... anyways, i will still give you an upvote

Comment: @Saswat yes I only just noticed the dates, I saw this question on my SO feed, and only now seen it's dated 2014!! :-| . I hope you solved the original issue!!